# GraphQL Client for Django with Bootrstrap Forntend

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap, graphql

I kinda wanted to use the Apollo Client, but sadly it would be too much work to migrate my Django+Bootstrap site to React or Angular.

I'm trying build a feature that requires sending queries to a third party GraphQL server. I was wondering what frontend Javascript library exists that is a good alternative to Apollo client? Would I have to just include what I need from [GraphQL JS](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) and build a custom library with webpack?

Comment: Note that in GraphQL the query is a standard HTML POST request with content being a chunk of text similar JSON and the response is a normal JSON object. JQuery or any other library can do such requests if you don't care to write a few queries asking for the exact data.

Comment: @Alejandro For my case, it'd be simpler to write the queries. I'm gonna need at least the graphql language as part of whatever Javascript package I use. If I need to, I can try to find an http and websockets JS library to handle the connections

Comment: Consider that "GraphQL language" don't exist in Javascript. It's just a string submited to a server sent as part of a POST request. Any web browser has the capability to do this, and tons of libraries enhance it some way or another.

Comment: @Alejandro Oh I see. I think I misunderstood you the first time. Just to check to see if I did understand, what you're saying is I can just send the query as a string in JSON via jQuery Ajax?

Comment: Almost! GraphQL queries are **very** similar to JSON, but not exactly the same (they're not valid JSON strictly speaking). But save for that, yes, you just send a normal POST request using JQuery or any other standard method you want. The result **is** standard JSON though, and you can parse it with any tool that handles normal JSON strings and deserialize into Javascript objects for utilization.

Comment: @Alejandro You're awesome! Thanks for helping me think that through.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I expressed a really big interest in GraphQL. I found out a great [article](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/graphql/GraphQL-Stack-Nodejs-Tools-Libraries-Frameworks-Explained-and-Compared/) that shows all library capabilities for having a GraphQL API. However, it only refers to Node.js applications, but as you ask for a client, you should be just fine. So, I would recommend to you, if you do not want to use the Apollo Client, to use Relay. I have not personally used it, but I have heard great things about it. It is supported and used by Facebook, as well it is great for scalable applications.

I hope that helps, good luck with your project!